# Excel VBA Copy Paste Transpose loop issue

Tags: excel, vba, loops, transpose

For A model in Excel I would like to copy and paste data from one sheet in a workbook to the other sheet in the workbook and transpose this data with the usage of a for next loop. Data from the workfile CME should be pasted in the workfile of RME. The total lines of data is 2420. However, since the ranges in the two different workbook are different and step sizes are different, I assume that i should use two different variables. When I try to run  this code, it will give me an error. the first to codes are an example how it should be done manually without a loop. Thereafter the loop starts. Already a lot of thanks for the person who can help me with this issue

I came up with the following formula:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Worksheets("CME").Range("J2:J10").Copy
Worksheets("RME").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

Worksheets("CME").Range("J12:J20").Copy
Worksheets("RME").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

For i = 11 To 2420 Step 10
    Worksheets("CME").Range (Cells(i + 11, 10)), Cells(i + 19, 10).Copy

    For j = 3 To 2420 Step 1
    Worksheets("RME").Range(Cells(j + 1, 2)).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Ca you give an example of existing data and expected output?

Comment: In Excel Workfile CME: copy range J2:J10 to transfer it to workfile RME to be pasted on B2:J2 so it is important to have a transpose function in it. 

For the next range I need to copy the range J12:J20 to transfer it to workfile RME to be pasted on B3:J3 and so on, therefore I need to create a loop right? With two different stepsizes for the copy and paste ranges

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got your question right, but the following code transposes a range starting at A1 in CME to a transposed range starting at A1 in RME, regardless of its size.

```
Sub Transpose()

Dim Table As Range
Set Table = Worksheets("CME").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))

For Each Cell In Table
    RowNo = Cell.Row
    ColNo = Cell.Column
    Worksheets("RME").Cells(ColNo, RowNo).Value = Cell.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: In Excel Workfile CME: copy range J2:J10 to transfer it to workfile RME to be pasted on B2:J2 so it is important to have a transpose function in it. 

For the next range I need to copy the range J12:J20 to transfer it to workfile RME to be pasted on B3:J3 and so on, therefore I need to create a loop right? With two different stepsizes for the copy and paste ranges.

Thanks a lot already!